# Did Kamadeva have green skin?

Tags: kama, kamadeva, color

I've sometimes seen descriptions and depictions of Kamadeva (Kama) as having green-colored skin, as in this [article](https://symbolsage.com/kamadeva-god-of-love/#:%7E:text=Cupid%2Dlike%20deities%20exist%20in,on%20a%20giant%20green%20parrot.). The picture in the link above shows it as dark green ([this one](https://www.hinduamerican.org/blog/cupid-sure-but-do-you-know-about-kamadeva-5-stories-of-love-and-lust-in-hinduism) does, too), while [these](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/Kama%2C_god_of_desire.jpg/220px-Kama%2C_god_of_desire.jpg) [two](https://www.hinduamerican.org/blog/cupid-sure-but-do-you-know-about-kamadeva-5-stories-of-love-and-lust-in-hinduism) here are lighter. [Rudraksha-ratna](https://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/articles/lord-kamadeva) says, on Kamadeva, that

> The God of love is illustrated as a handsome, youthful, winged, young man with a greenish (or sometimes reddish) complexion.

However, most of the other images I found online show him having a normal complexion. So, what color was Kamadeva's skin? Was it green, reddish, or normal? And where did the idea of it being green originate? Does it have any meaning?